# How to pass a UIImageView from UITableView (custom cell) to DetailViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm tearing my hair out over this one. I'm trying to pass an image URL from my `TableViewController` to my `DetailViewController` (`FullArticleViewController`) so that I can set the `UIImageView`, and nothing I try seems to be working. See my code below:

**`MyTableViewController.h`**

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UIViewController  <UISearchBarDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UITableView *DoctorsTableView;

    NSArray *Doctors;
    NSMutableData *data;

    NSArray *searchResults;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *cellImageLink;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
```

**`MyTableViewController.m`**

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {

            static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"DoctorsCell";

            DoctorsCell *cell = (DoctorsCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DoctorsCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            } 

            if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

                NSLog(@"Using the search results");

            cell.firstnameLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];

            cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Opening Paragraph"];

            NSString *firstLink = [[NSString alloc] init];

            firstLink = [[[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Image"] objectForKey:@"filename"];

            NSString *secondLink = [[NSString alloc] init];

            secondLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL HERE%@",firstLink];
              NSLog(@"second link is %@", secondLink);


            cellImageLink = secondLink;

            [cell.featureImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];


            } else {
                NSLog(@"Using the Full List!");


                cell.firstnameLabel.text = [[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];

                cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Opening Paragraph"];

                NSString *firstLink = [[NSString alloc] init];

                firstLink = [[[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Image"] objectForKey:@"filename"];

                NSString *secondLink = [[NSString alloc] init];

                secondLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL HERE%@",firstLink];
                NSLog(@"second link is %@", secondLink);


                cellImageLink = secondLink;

                [cell.featureImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];

            }

            return cell;
        }


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        FullArticleViewController *detailViewController = [[FullArticleViewController alloc]
                                                            initWithNibName:@"FullArticleViewController" bundle:nil];
        if ([searchResults count]) {

            detailViewController.title = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];

            detailViewController.articleDetail = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        } else {

            detailViewController.title = [[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];

            detailViewController.articleDetail = [Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            NSLog(@"%@", Doctors);

        }

FullArticleViewController *viewController = [[FullArticleViewController alloc]
                                                     initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController"
                                                     bundle:nil];
 viewController.featureImage = searchResults[indexPath.row][@"Image"][@"filename"];
                                                                 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    }
```

**FullArticleViewController.h** (detailview)

```
@interface FullArticleViewController : UIViewController

{

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    IBOutlet UILabel *firstnameLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *descriptionLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *bodyLabel;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDictionary *articleDetail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *featureImage;

-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender;
```

**FullArticleViewController.m** (detailview)

```
 #import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h"
    #import "FullArticleViewController.h"
    #import "DoctorsCell.h"
    #import "MyTableViewController.h"


    @interface FullArticleViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation FullArticleViewController

    @synthesize articleDetail;
    @synthesize featureImage;


    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization

        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

featureImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

        [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 5000)];

        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

        firstnameLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"node_title"];
        descriptionLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"Opening Paragraph"];
        bodyLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"Body"];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MyTableViewController.m**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    FullArticleViewController *detailViewController = [[FullArticleViewController alloc]
                                    initWithNibName:@"FullArticleViewController" bundle:nil];
    if ([searchResults count]) {
        detailViewController.title = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];
        detailViewController.articleDetail = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailViewController.cellImageLink = searchResults[indexPath.row][@"Image"][@"filename"];
    } else {
        detailViewController.title = [[Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];
        detailViewController.articleDetail = [Doctors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailViewController.cellImageLink =  Doctors[indexPath.row][@"Image"][@"filename"];
    }
        NSLog(@"cellImageLink = %@", detailViewController.cellImageLink);
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES]; 
}
```

**FullArticleViewController.m**

Set the image in `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"cellImageLink = %@", self.cellImageLink);

    featureImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    //maybe set the frame here?
    [self.featureImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domainnamehere.com/%@",cellImageLink]]];

    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 5000)];

    firstnameLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"node_title"];
    descriptionLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"Opening Paragraph"];
    bodyLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"Body"];
}
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not using Storyboard to pass the image; just passing from a viewcontroller to xib (detailView).

Comment: See my code edited above. Implemented your answer, and my detailViewController is still telling me that featureImage is null. :/

Comment: SO CLOSE lol. Okay so cellImageLink is no longer null. It gives me the file name of the image, but the entire url isn't included so it's not showing the picture. Console says: cellImageLink = who-uses-facebook.jpg But I need cellImageLink to be the full URL (and not just the image name): http://domainnamehere.com/imagename.jpg

Comment: `[self.featureImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domainnamehere.com/%@",cellImageLink]]];`

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would set detail view properties upon cell selection right before pushing the new view controller. Something like this would do it:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
  FullArticleViewController *detailView = [[FullArticleViewController alloc] init];
  detailView.articleDetail = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController detailView animated:YES];
}
```

Notice I am using the default initializer for your view controller and am also assuming you are using a `UINavigationController`. You may need to change one or both of these to fit your code.

Then, you would want to use the same `SDWebImage` category to set the image url in `viewDidLoad` of `FullArticleViewController.m`. It will probably look something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 5000)];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    firstnameLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"node_title"];
    descriptionLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"Opening Paragraph"];
    bodyLabel.text = [articleDetail objectForKey:@"Body"];

    [self.featureImage sd_setImageWithURL::[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.articleDetail objectForKey:@"Image"] objectForKey:@"filename"]];
}
```

Comment: Hi Dima! I implemented your answer, and for some reason the console is telling me that featureImage is null.

Comment: That is unrelated to the answer. Something must be wrong with your view. You have it tagged as an `IBOutlet`. Is it actually set in your XIB?